# Order and delivery DW

Tags: data-warehouse, fact-table

Now I am working on my project I need to create a data warehouse, we have an application where a client can place an order, One order can be sent in multiple deliveries(even for the same product for example if he asked for 5 when can send the first time only 3 and the second time we will send the rest ).

Now I am thinking of creating two fact tables: **Order** (client,order_id, product, quantity,dateOrder)and should I add a new column to design if the order is canceled or treated, or being treated(if we send part of the order) so this column should be changed we can add a new column date change.
**Delivery** (client,orderid,ShippingDateKey ,OrderDateKey,ProductKey,QuantityShipped, quantity NeedTobe shipped,changeDate)

**OR**
I should create only one fact table that has all the information(orderdate,customer ,product ,shipdate'but first it is Null!!!' and it will be changed each time we deliver a part of the order of this product,shiped quantity,orderquantity).

**PS** OrderKey and OrderLineNumber should it be in a dimension or we can add it to our fact table as Primary key?

**Second thing** wether i am going to use first or second method we gonna update information of our DW but we know that we don't have the right to delete or change anything from DW!!

Thank you

Comment: A data warehouse should be designed based on your reporting requirements, not on the structure/operation of a source system. Once you have defined your reporting requirements you should have a much better idea how to design your fact tables

Comment: ok thank you for your answer, but i want to ask for example if i create dimension OrderStatus in my table fact order this column will get change can i modify that column by the new value ,Or for example Quantity shipped wil change by the time can i modify it (SCD)!! cause i know that we can not delete or modify data from our DW

Comment: You can add/change/delete whatever data you want to in your DW, depending on your requirements. If Order status changes then it's up to you whether you create a new fact record or update an existing one. If shipped quantity changes then if this due to error correction than you would probably update the fact; if it changes because there are multiple shipments per order then you'd probably create a record per shipment

Comment: yes, there are multiple shipments per order so okay each time there is a new shipment for an order I will add a new record. But I have one other question my goal is to see how much quantity per product per order is shipped and need to be shipped, the duration between the order and final shipment, that's why I decided to create one table fact that has all the column But when we place an order ship date is null(there is no shipment yet)so it should be null 'datekeyShip' is it fine!!!!

Comment: It is not good practice to have null keys in your fact table. It is normal to have a record in each dimension to indicate no/unknown data - often with a key value of 0 or -1 - and to populate the fact table with these values when there is no data for a particular key

Comment: Then I think the best thing to do is to create 2 Fact table one for order second for Shipp, the fact table to see the order and the status of each order(doing an update on that column treated, canceled, is being treated(when we send ),orderedQT,shippedQT 'first it's 0' then it will increment by time OR I can add a new record each time the order status get changed or the qt changed But I don't see it's a good way) and I will create Second Ship each time we ship for the same order we add a new record. Thank you So much for your help, time .